# Client Local Queue in Red Hat AMQ

Tags: redhat, activemq-artemis, amq

We have a network of Red Hat AMQ 7.2 brokers with Master/Slave configuration. The client application publish / subscribe to topics on the broker cluster.

How do we handle the situation wherein the network connectivity between the client application and the broker cluster goes down? Does Red Hat AMQ have a native solution like client local queue and a jms to jms bridge between local queue and remote broker so that network connectivity failure will not result in loss of messages.

Comment: red hat amq 7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be possible for you to craft a solution where your clients use a local broker and that local broker bridges messages to the remote broker. The local broker will, of course, never lose network connectivity with the local clients since everything is *local*. However, if the local broker loses connectivity with the remote broker it will act as a buffer and store messages until connectivity with the remote broker is restored. Once connectivity is restored then the local broker will forward the stored messages to the remote broker. This will allow the producers to keep working as if nothing has actually failed. However, you would need to configure all this manually.

That said, even if you don't implement such a solution there is absolutely no need for any message *loss* even when clients encounter a loss of network connectivity. If you send durable (i.e. persistent) messages then by default the client will wait for a response from the broker telling the client that the broker successfully received and persisted the message to disk. More complex interactions might require local JMS transactions and even more complex interactions may require XA transactions. In any event, there are ways to eliminate the possibility of message *loss* without implementing some kind of local broker solution.